# Two-way repeated measure Anova R with ezANOVA error, One or more cells is missing data

Tags: r, missing-data, anova

I've created this minimal dataset for the example :

```
data_long <- data.frame(Subject = factor(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)), 
                            Trt = factor(c("T1","T2","T3","T1","T2","T3")),
                            Day = factor(c(7, 7, 7, 14, 14, 14)),
                            Value = c(7.6, 5.3, 8.6, 12.4, 11.2, 11))
```

But when I try to make a two way repeated measure ANOVA with ezANOVA, I have this error :

```
m2 <- ezANOVA(data = data_long, dv = Value, wid = Subject, within = c(Day,Trt))

Erreur dans ezANOVA_main(data = data, dv = dv, wid = wid, within = within,  : 
  One or more cells is missing data. Try using ezDesign() to check your data.
```

I definitely don't have missing data, but this error still occurs. Is there a way to fix that ?

Thank you in advance,

Yemoloh

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having is that for each level of the Trt factor one single participant is present.

You can see this by adding the same participants to each condition (so that each participant is present for each Trt condition):

```
data_long <- data.frame(Subject = factor(rep(1:3, each = 6)), 
                    Trt = factor(rep(c("T1", "T2", "T3"), times = 6)),
                    Day = factor(rep(c(7, 14), times = 3, each = 3)),
                    Value = rnorm(n = 18, mean = 6))
```

With this data structure you would be able to run the ANOVA as you specified it.